# How to use different keys in input and output when using Encodable protocol?

Tags: swift, encodable

Expected this: `name` -> `fullname`

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "fullname"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    }
}

let jsonString = """
{
    "name": "John"
}
"""

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
   let decodedPerson = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Person.self, from: jsonData) {
    print(decodedPerson.name) // Output: "John"
}

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
if let encodedData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(decodedPerson),
   let encodedString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(encodedString)
}
```

But the reality that second output produce this:

```swift
{
  "name" : "John"
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to use "name" as the key when decoding, and use "fullname" when encoding?

Comment: When I run your code, the call to `decode` fails with a keyNotFound error. This makes sense since you try to decode with `fullName` but the JSON has a key of `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to decode the `name` key and output the `fullname` key (which is really confusing and means your code can't decode the JSON that it generates) then you need to update the `CodingKeys` to:

```swift
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case fullname = "fullname"
    case name = "name"
}
```

and you need to update the `encode` method to use `.fullname` instead of `.name`.

Then you can parse the original JSON with the `name` key and then generate new JSON with a `fullname` key.

Here's your code with some cleanup and the changes I suggest:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fullname = "fullname"
        case name = "name"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .fullname) // Use fullname
    }
}

let jsonString = """
{
    "name": "John"
}
"""

do {
    let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)! // this can't fail
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decodedPerson = try jsonDecoder.decode(Person.self, from: jsonData)
    print(decodedPerson.name) // Output: "John"

    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    let encodedData = try jsonEncoder.encode(decodedPerson)
    let encodedString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)! // This won't fail either
    print(encodedString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The output is:

> John
> {
> "fullname" : "John"
> }

---

Just to reiterate. This is a bad idea. Your `Person` class, with these changes, can't decode the JSON that it encodes. Are you really sure that is what you want?